# Vue animation transitions between multiple lists

Tags: animation, vue.js, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a Kanban board in Vue where users can click and drag items from one column to another. I'm using [Vue Draggable](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable) for the click-and-drag functionality, and can successfully drag items from one array to another.

I'd like a smooth transition when adding items to one array to another. The example in [the transition documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Move-Transitions) using `animation-move` CSS class works fine for transitions *within* an array, but not *between* arrays.

Is there any way to get a smooth animation using the built in Vue transition API when moving items from one array to another?

Comment: Would that be [List enter and leave transitions](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Entering-Leaving-Transitions)?

Comment: Thanks Roy J, theoretically that should work with two array (removing from one, adding to the other), but it's still not working for me. Beginning to suspect it might be something to do with how Vue Draggable is handling the array manipulation, not a problem with Vue transitions themselves.